# Return IGrouping of anonymous IEnumerable to present on DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid, igrouping

On WPF I build this code
I want to show on datagrid the sum of "Desc" for each "PID"

```
public class Event
{
    public int PID { get; set; }
    public int Desc { get; set; }
}

private List<Event> data;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    data = new List<Event>() 
    {
        new Event() { PID = 1, Desc=2 },
        new Event() { PID = 1, Desc=3 },
        new Event() { PID = 2, Desc=4 },
        new Event() { PID = 2, Desc=5 },
        new Event() { PID = 3, Desc=6 }
    };

    var result =
        from d in data
        group d.Desc by d.PID into pg
        select new { ID = pg.Key,  SUM = pg.Sum() };

    datagrid.ItemsSource = result;
}
```

And the XAML is

```
<DataGrid Name="datagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding SUM}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

that work well!
but this is not good,

What I want to do is return that "var result" from function and binding like I did to DataGrid
How can I do this?

This is from `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,???>>`
on ??? there is anonymous type....

so how can I return this from function and binding like I did on DataGrid?

Thanks!

Comment: You can simply return `IEnumerable` if this method will be used to bind list of  _things_. `private IEnumerable GetData()`. Since [ItemsSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) property accepts `IEnumerable` this should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need a class to represent each item of your sequence. This way your result wouldn't be a sequence of objects of an anonymous type, but it would be sequence of objects of a specific type.

```
public class Result 
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int Sum { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will define a method like below:

```
public IEnumerable<Result> GetResults()
{
    data = new List<Event>() 
    {
        new Event() { PID = 1, Desc=2 },
        new Event() { PID = 1, Desc=3 },
        new Event() { PID = 2, Desc=4 },
        new Event() { PID = 2, Desc=5 },
        new Event() { PID = 3, Desc=6 }
    };

    var result = from d in data
                 group d.Desc by d.PID into pg
                 select new Result
                 { 
                     Id = pg.Key,  
                     Sum = pg.Sum()
                 };

    return result;
}
```

and then in your `MainWindow` method you will call this method.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    datagrid.ItemsSource = GetResults();
}
```

I have `supposed` that you have defined this method in the same class. It is quite possible that this is not a good practice. So if you define this method in another class, you have to create first an object of this class and later call the `GetResults` method of this object.

Furthermore, I attempted to make a slight change in the naming. It is more common to use camel case naming and not use capital letters for all the letters. That being said, you have also to make a slight change in your xaml code.

```
<DataGrid Name="datagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Sum}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: but how you can define Result like that
this is Igouping of int and anonimus type....
how the returning type is IEnumerable<Result>
here what i try accorind to yiu...

Comment: The result of `group by` is an `IGrouping`. Then you project the values of `IGrouping` to a sequence of `Result`. Note that for each group, pg, you create a new `Result` object. It like in your original code. At the end you didn't have an `IGrouping` result but a sequence of objects of an anonymous type.

Comment: Note here `select new`. You have forgotten the `Result`, `select new Result`.

Comment: yeh...
buy igrouping is igouping <key, index>
key is here int (the id) and index is anonimus
so the  Result  change only the index no?

Comment: No, it isn't corect. Did you try the code I have written above? Regarding the anonymous part: whenever your write `select { }` in linq, you create an a object of anonymous type for the input sequence. That's all. Furthermore, using `select` we say that we make a projection of the elements of the input sequence to another sequence. If you don't specify the type of the object you create in a projection then it's type would be anonymous. Otherwise, it would have a specific type.