# How can I make a GroupBy in VB.Net whose results can be returned from a function?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have to write a method returning a list of objects grouped by certain properties of those objects. I can succesfully make it with linq's GroupBy, but using anonymous types, which I can't send back to the caller. If I try to use a class to store the IGrouping part as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709550/return-igrouping-of-anonymous-ienumerable-to-present-on-datagrid), the .GroupBy does not groups at all - it's just like if the Key keywords were missing, but I can't use them in a strongly typed class.

I've searched a lot - more because I'm too lazy to write a question than because of following stackoverflow question guidelines - but most of the stuff I've found is either C# related, which doesn't have the issue of the Key keyword, or it's about single-column GroupBy's, or it uses anonymous types since it doesn't care about returning parameteres from a function or sub, so I've made a small program to illustrate the situation.

```
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1

    Public Class TrackHist
        Public Property Data As DateTime
        Public Property Esdvn As String
        Public Property Cmnts As String
        Public Property IdCnt As String
    End Class

    Public Class GroupedTrack
        Public Property Data As DateTime
        Public Property Esdvn As String
    End Class

    Function Group(lista As List(Of TrackHist)) As List(Of IGrouping(Of GroupedTrack, List(Of TrackHist)))
        Return lista.GroupBy(Function(f) New GroupedTrack With {.Data = f.Data, .Esdvn = f.Esdvn}).ToList
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim array As New List(Of TrackHist)
        array.Add(New TrackHist() With {.Data = DateTime.ParseExact("10/01/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), .Cmnts = "Nothing", .Esdvn = "BIL", .IdCnt = "CN134234"})
        array.Add(New TrackHist() With {.Data = DateTime.ParseExact("10/01/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), .Cmnts = "Nothing", .Esdvn = "BIL", .IdCnt = "CN284235"})
        array.Add(New TrackHist() With {.Data = DateTime.ParseExact("10/01/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), .Cmnts = "Nothing", .Esdvn = "BIL", .IdCnt = "CN660003"})
        array.Add(New TrackHist() With {.Data = DateTime.ParseExact("12/01/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), .Cmnts = "Nothing", .Esdvn = "LOA", .IdCnt = "CN134234"})
        array.Add(New TrackHist() With {.Data = DateTime.ParseExact("12/01/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), .Cmnts = "Nothing", .Esdvn = "LOA", .IdCnt = "CN284235"})
        array.Add(New TrackHist() With {.Data = DateTime.ParseExact("13/01/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), .Cmnts = "Nothing", .Esdvn = "LOA", .IdCnt = "CN660003"})
        array.Add(New TrackHist() With {.Data = DateTime.ParseExact("15/01/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), .Cmnts = "Nothing", .Esdvn = "INSP", .IdCnt = "CN134234"})
        array.Add(New TrackHist() With {.Data = DateTime.ParseExact("16/01/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), .Cmnts = "Nothing", .Esdvn = "DEP", .IdCnt = "CN284235"})
        array.Add(New TrackHist() With {.Data = DateTime.ParseExact("16/01/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), .Cmnts = "Nothing", .Esdvn = "DEP", .IdCnt = "CN660003"})

        Dim groupedAnonymous = array.GroupBy(Function(f) New With {Key f.Data, Key f.Esdvn}).ToList
        Dim groupedTyped = Group(array)

        Console.WriteLine("Grouped anonymous: {0} registers", groupedAnonymous.Count)
        Console.WriteLine("Grouped typed: {0} registers", groupedTyped.Count)
    End Sub

End Module
```

This program yields the following output:

Grouped anonymous: 5 registers
Grouped typed: 9 registers

Or, in other words, the grouping with strongly typed objects is not grouping at all. So, what's the correct way to make a GroupBy in VB.Net whose results can be returned from a function?

Comment: are the two groupBy functions meant to be equivalent? (the one in the function and the one in Main). Because at the moment they are not the same, which might be why you get different results. The fact that it's returned from a function is not really relevant.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know how to compare `GroupedTrack` to another `GroupedTrack` and compares them by reference.

Comment: Am I the only one getting an error on the `Return lista.GroupBy(Function(f) New GroupedTrack With {.Data = f.Data, .Esdvn = f.Esdvn}).ToList` line?

Comment: @JoshPart No, it should be `Function Group(lista As List(Of TrackHist)) As List(Of IGrouping(Of GroupedTrack, TrackHist))`.

Comment: To expand on what @Slai said, `GroupedTrack` should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` using the `Data` and `Esdvn` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting Slai's and Mark's comments into an answer:

Your problem is that you haven't defined a way to compare a `GroupedTrack` object to another `GroupedTrack` object; therefore when these objects are created they are compared by reference, and because all of them are actually different objects, you get 9 different values.

What you have to do is to override both `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` functions so the compiler now how to compare the `GroupedTrack` objects by value.

Something like this:

```
Public Class GroupedTrack
    Public Property Data As DateTime
    Public Property Esdvn As String

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing Then Return False
        If TypeOf obj IsNot GroupedTrack Then Return False
        Return Me.Data = CType(obj, GroupedTrack).Data And Me.Esdvn = CType(obj, GroupedTrack).Esdvn
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return (Me.Data.ToString() & Me.Esdvn).GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

(And when you are on that, correct your function definition to

```
Function Group(lista As List(Of TrackHist)) As List(Of IGrouping(Of GroupedTrack, TrackHist))
```

)

This way, both groupings yield a list of 5 elements each.

Comment: Given that it was a problem with the Key keyword, I was suspecting that lacking a proper comparision method was the culprit, but I refused to believe that much hasle was necessary. :p  Many thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 1):

If the "proper" way seems like too much hassle, the lazy way is to use comparable type for the key:

```
Function Group(items As IEnumerable(Of TrackHist)) As ILookup(Of String, TrackHist)
    Return items.ToLookup(Function(t) t.Esdvn & t.Data)
End Function
```

I would not even bother with making the function, but the point is that `String` already implements the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods so you don't have to. 
The `.GroupBy` LINQ extension uses `Lookup` to get the groups, so you can avoid the `.ToList` by using the `Lookup` directly.

If you rather compare the key items separately, you can cast the anonymous type to `Object`:

```
 Dim lookup As ILookup(Of Object, TrackHist) = 
         array.ToLookup(Function(t) CObj(New With {Key t.Data, Key t.Esdvn}))
```

Comment: Interesting! I'll go the proper way, though - it's not really a problem, I just thought that it had to be a simpler way.